# PHPEXCEL add separator in a cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I export some of my db into a csv using PhpExcel.
Because I have quite some corrupted data, I check them and display the errors when necessary.

So I would like to display in my error message when a field contains my separator (otherwise it would mess with my pagination) :

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->_objErrorPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->setDelimiter('|');
    $objWriter->setEnclosure( '' );
    $objWriter->setUseBOM( true );
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas( false );
    $objWriter->save( $strOutputFile );
    unset( $objWriter );
```

When I save my error message (for an email address like em|ail@email.com) :

```
$this->$strExcelFileName->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('F' . $intRow, $strError );
```

Instead of saving in my F cell

> EMail contains "|" character

I end up

> EMail contains

in F, and

> |

character in G.

I then have the same problem when I save the email in the spreadsheet, it is cut in 2 cells.

Thanks for your time and advices :)

Comment: Why not just use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)? PHPExcel is over-complicating matters.

Comment: I kind of agree, but unfortunately, the choice of using it wasn't mine...

Comment: Well I'm fairly certain that your problem is going to be related to `$objWriter->setEnclosure( '' );` - you are specifying an empty field enclosure, which means that there is no way to quote a string that contains a separator, so obviously it will be viewed as a field delimiter and not a literal character. I think you need to do something like `$objWriter->setEnclosure( '"' );`

Comment: As a side note, I'm not certain that a pipe in the local portion of an email address is illegal anyway. Email addresses can have a lot more entropy than is usually allowed by mail providers, IIRC just about the only disallowed character in the local name is `@` (for obvious reasons). **EDIT** Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it was my setEnclosure which was wrong. Setting it to ("'") solves the problem !

Comment: And about the | character, I have a very low flexibility, and people working with this spreadsheet won't make the difference between a | in the string or it as a separator, that's why I need to escape it, even if it won't be correct as it is still a valid email ! (zend email validator also doesn't consider it as an error !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided by DaveRandom ! :

> Well I'm fairly certain that your problem is going to be related to
>   $objWriter->setEnclosure( '' ); - you are specifying an empty field
>   enclosure, which means that there is no way to quote a string that
>   contains a separator, so obviously it will be viewed as a field
>   delimiter and not a literal character. I think you need to do
>   something like $objWriter->setEnclosure( '"' );